# Elasticsearch explain error - Document mapping type name can't start with '_'

Tags: elasticsearch, explain

**strong text**Can somebody tell me please what means this Elasticsearch error which throws me an explain query 192.132.4.43:9200/search/_search&explain=true

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "invalid_type_name_exception",
                "reason": "Document mapping type name can't start with '_', found: [_search&explain=true]"
            }
        ],
        "type": "invalid_type_name_exception",
        "reason": "Document mapping type name can't start with '_', found: [_search&explain=true]"
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

Query without explain works well but when I call explain it throws me this error. Elasticsearch is 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a small typo in your URL

```
192.132.4.43:9200/search/_search?explain=true
                                ^
                                |
                     use ? here instead of &
```